# SQL copy from one table to appropriate field into another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query which was written by very helpful member of stackoverflow

```
update smf_members a, 
(select user_id,
sum(if(karma_action='+',1,0)) karma_good,
sum(if(karma_action='-',1,0)) karma_bad
from phpbb_karma
group by user_id) b
set a.karma_good=b.karma_good, a.karma_bad = b.karma_bad
where a.id_member = b.user_id;
```

it was written for the following purpose:
I need to transfer data from karma mod in phpbb to karma in smf.

Phpbb has a table phpbb_karma which is basically a karma log. Important fields we need to focus on are user_id (user which got the karma) and karma_action (positive or negative karma, shown as + or -).

I would need a query to count all the pluses and minuses and then copy the given results for each unique user_id into smf_members table under appropriate id_member (user_id field in smf) and karma_good (all the pluses) and karma_bad (all the minuses).

Now I need a little variation on it - transfer data from phpbb_karma into mybb_reputation

i need to transfer following fields:

```
user_id -> uid
post_id -> pid
poster_id -> adduid
karma_action -> reputation (if its +, then 1, if its -, then -1)
karma_time -> dateline
comment_text -> comments
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean an insert like:

```
insert into mybb_reputation (uid, pid, adduid, reputation, dateline, comments)
select user_id as uid, post_id as pid, poster_id as adduid, case when karma_action= '+' then 1 when karma_reputation='-' then -1 end as reputation, karma_time as dateline, comment_text as comments from phpbb_karma
```

Comment: I modified it a bit - insert into mybb_reputation (uid, pid, adduid, reputation, dateline, comments)
select user_id as uid, post_id as pid, case when karma_action= '+'  then 1 when karma_action='-' then -1 end as reputation, karma_time as dateline, comment_text as comments
from phpbb_karma

Comment: and got the following error - #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: i forgot the column poster_id in the second query i just updated the query

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list', and user_id is a column in php_karma

Comment: this one worked, I had to add from phpbb_karma - insert into mybb_reputation (uid, pid, adduid, reputation, dateline, comments)
select user_id as uid, post_id as pid, poster_id as adduid, case when karma_action= '+' then 1 when karma_action='-' then -1 end as reputation, karma_time as dateline, comment_text as comments
from phpbb_karma